# Can I access my own account logs at Godaddy without a subpoena?

Tags: privacy, legal, account-security, domain-admin

I have some evidence that our Godaddy domain account has been tampered with, by a former administrator with access to the account credentials.

To prove that the account was accessed, I need, at the very least, the timestamps of successful account login.

Godaddy refused to process my request for access logs to my own account, and responded

> Thank you for your email  We would be un able to provide logs with out a subpoena.  Please review the subpoena policy below.
>
> https://my.godaddy.com/agreements/showdoc.aspx?pageid=CIVIL_SUBPOENA

Wikipedia's ariticle on [subpoena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpoena) states that:

> Subpoenas are usually issued by the clerk of the court in the name of the judge presiding over the case

This implies that there is a court case. But we have no court case yet, as I am still in the process of gathering information to support the case.

Questions:

1. Is Godaddy entitled to refuse access to my own account information, except under legal compulsion?
2. Are there other ways of accessing this information?

Comment: This is a legal question and you'll probably be better off posting it at the legal stack exchange.

Comment: I think you will be wasting your time trying to get that from GoDaddy without any legal support.

Comment: For the legal aspects you should consult legal.SE, or better, a lawyer.  I think you can edit that out and may still have a on-topic question here about methods for accessing those logs.

Comment: "But we have no court case yet, as I am still in the process of gathering information to support the case" -- This is not how cases are built. Get a lawyer involved before you compromise this investigation altogether.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I agree it is rather a borderline case. The help page lists 'policies' and 'incident response' as valid subjects. I value your responses as IT pros, who might have gone through these aspects personally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already said, this is more a legal question not a security question. But to be blunt the answers aren't so long:

1. Yes they have full rights to deny anything you are not entitled to by the contract you agreed to when you signed up. Think of it this way, you host a server and you have users that can log in. do they have rights to your back-end logs? probably not. nor would you want them to. Do they have rights to their profile information? Maybe, depends on your TOS.
2. Privacy policy is the only other way. privacy policy throughout history has been the best way to get information or hold accountable a company that states one. since not adhering to it can be deemed fraud. I don't know go-daddy's PP, nor do i know if it would help you. but if for nothing else, give it a look through and see if you can leverage any part of it to come back to them without having to go through a legal process.

That pretty much sums it up i think.

Comment: [Godaddy's PP](https://www.godaddy.com/Agreements/Privacy.aspx)_As is true of most websites, we gather certain information automatically and store it in log files.  This information may include Internet protocol (IP) addresses, browser type, Internet service provider (ISP), referring/exit pages, operating system, date/time stamp and/or clickstream data.  We use this information gathered about you from our Site or mobile application to help personalize search results, diagnose problems with our server, and to administer our Site and mobile applications. ... _

Comment: no mention of any use of or access to this information for the account holder